# Using page directive instead of master in umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, content-management-system, umbraco

Currently I have a master page setup in Umbraco:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/umbraco/masterpages/default.master" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
```

That page is working fine, I can edit structure and have placeholders that work fine.

The issue I am having is creating a child template as a page, not master.

Something Like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/masterpages/master.master" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
```

The error I am getting is: `Parser Error Message: The directive 'page' is unknown.`

From what I gathered so far this is due to the fact that the file extension is .master instead of .aspx.

That being said, I was able to change the file extension being that I am working with VS, but when you change the file extension Umbraco no longer reads from that file and just shows a blank template which on save will recreate the .master.

Not sure if there is some config file that needs to be changed as well but it seems like you should only have to update that path to .aspx.

The thing that is driving me crazy is I had this setup and managed to break it.

I have no idea what I am doing differently.

It may be something stupid.

I haven't found any simple clear cut solutions to what the issue is exactly and how to solve it.

Any clarity on the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're trying to create a child template as a page and not a master *and* expect it be visible in Umbraco. This isn't how Umbraco works.

Whilst in **webforms** mode, Umbraco only uses masterpages to generate pages. You can create child masterpages and this is a common practice. However 'pages' are created dynamically by Umbraco so you don't have to.

If this is confusing you then I'm afraid you're best option is to read the documentation at [our.umbraco.org](http://our.umbraco.org) and start with the basics.

If you are trying to achieve something specific, then you need to provide more information in your question.